# Replace part of innerHTML without reloading embedded videos

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a div with id #test that contains lots of html, including some youtube-embeds etc.

Somewhere in this div there is this text: "[test]"

I need to replace that text with "(works!)".

The normal way of doing this would of course be:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test").replace("[test]","(works!)");
```

But the problem is that if i do that the youtube-embeds will reload, which is not acceptable.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to target the specific elements rather than the parent block. Since the DOM is changing the videos are repainted to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `TextNode (textContent)` will help you, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974773%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) documentation IE9, other browsers also should support it

Answer (score 0):

Change your page so that

```
[test]
```

becomes

```
<span id="replace-me">[test]</span>
```

now use the following js to find and change it

```
document.getElementById('replace-me').text = '(works!)';
```

If you need to change more than one place, then use a `class` instead of an `id` and use `document.getElementsByClassName` and iterate over the returned elements and change them one by one.

Alternatively, you can use jQuery and do it even simpler like this:

```
$('#replace-me').text('(works!)');
```

Now for this single replacement using jQuery is probably overkill, but if you need to change multiple places (by class name), jQuery would definitely come in handy :)